Why boil food in milk?
I've seen instructions for sausages (e.g. Morteau sausage) which say to boil in milk or water, and I remember distinctly a schoolteacher telling me that shark needed to be boiled in milk for some time before eating.
What are the effects/processes that happen here? Does the fat in milk help dissolve and remove certain flavours or reduce fat loss from the food being cooked? Here I am expecting that the milk is discarded after the process.
I reviewed Google and What is the effect of poaching fish in milk? but didn't see any information on mechanisms.

I also spent some time searching for whether milk does things to urea or nitrogen compounds but was unable to find anything relevant due to a lack of skill.
